# How can I make a multi-line text variable readonly in the RITM and Catalog Tasks?

Tags: servicenow

I have a Catalog Item, and I am unable to set the Multi Line Text variable to readonly in the RITM and TASKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** Rename the field.

I had a Multi Line Text variable named "comments" in a Catalog Item that would not become readonly in the RITM and Tasks, (I was using client scripts, and no other fields had this problem).  The issue was that the name "comments" was conflicting with something and causing it to remain editable (maybe "comments" is a reserved term in SNow?).  Once I changed name to anything else (e.g. comments_1), it began working as expected.

This is in Madrid.

Comment: I just wrote that field names are by default prefixed so there should not be any collision and then I realized you were talking about variables ;) anyway, that is weird, I don't think comments is a restricted keyword. Maybe you already had another variable on the same form called "comments" which can sometimes cause issues. anyway, glad it works.